# Get the right values from a JSON array using Google's Geocoding API

Tags: php, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the `Google Geocoding API`, and `PHP` (cURL) to get the JSON array.
That's all working fine.
The problem is that not every output is the same.

Example:

I have two addresses:

1. Dam 1, Amsterdam
2. Kurfürstendamm 1, Berlin

For the Amsterdam address the count of `$array['results'][0]['address_components']` is 8 and the one for Berlin 7.

**JSON output:**

**Amsterdam:**

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1",
               "short_name" : "1",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dam",
               "short_name" : "Dam",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Centrum",
               "short_name" : "Centrum",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amsterdam",
               "short_name" : "Amsterdam",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amsterdam",
               "short_name" : "Amsterdam",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Noord-Holland",
               "short_name" : "NH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nederland",
               "short_name" : "NL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "1012 JS",
               "short_name" : "1012 JS",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Dam 1, 1012 JS Amsterdam, Nederland",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.3740904,
                  "lng" : 4.8951464
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.37303319999999,
                  "lng" : 4.893589
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.3735618,
               "lng" : 4.8943677
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.37491078029149,
                  "lng" : 4.895716680291502
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.3722128197085,
                  "lng" : 4.893018719708498
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ46bYaccJxkcRR1k-7Pl25Kg",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**Berlin:**

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1",
               "short_name" : "1",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kurfürstendamm",
               "short_name" : "Kurfürstendamm",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bezirk Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf",
               "short_name" : "Bezirk Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Berlin",
               "short_name" : "Berlin",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Berlin",
               "short_name" : "Berlin",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Duitsland",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "10719",
               "short_name" : "10719",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kurfürstendamm 1, 10719 Berlin, Duitsland",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.50440769999999,
                  "lng" : 13.3337799
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.5043971,
                  "lng" : 13.3337737
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.50440769999999,
               "lng" : 13.3337737
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.50575138029149,
                  "lng" : 13.3351257802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.5030534197085,
                  "lng" : 13.3324278197085
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "EixLdXJmw7xyc3RlbmRhbW0gMSwgMTA3MTkgQmVybGluLCBEZXV0c2NobGFuZA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

As you can see the country and postalcode indexes are different (country: 6 and 5, postalcode 7 and 6)

When I want to show the street, housenumber, postalcode, city and country for both cities something like this:

```
echo 'Street = '.$array['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'].'<br />';
echo 'Housenumber = '.$array['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'].'<br />';
echo 'Postalcode = '.$array['results'][0]['address_components'][7]['long_name'].'<br />';
echo 'City = '.$array['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name'].'<br />';
echo 'Country = '.$array['results'][0]['address_components'][6]['long_name'].'<br />';
```

**It shows the following output:**

**Amsterdam:**

```
Street = Dam
Housenumber = 1
Postalcode = 1012 JS
City = Amsterdam
Country = Netherlands
```

**Berlin:**

```
Street = Kurfürstendamm
Housenumber = 1

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in .... on line ....
Postalcode = 
City = Berlin
Country = 10719
```

So the question is, how can I get the `"long_name"` per `"types"` in the `"address_components"` array?

Or maybe there are even better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following code below to convert the JSON reponse to an array with the address components as keys:

```
function convertAddress($json)
{

    $data = json_decode($json);

    $address = array();

    foreach($data['results']['address_components'] AS $_component){

        $key = array_values($_component['types']);
        $address[$key[0]] = $_component;

    }

    return $address;

}
```

This works great for me with your test data, you can then access data like so:

```
$address = convertAddress($berlin_address);
print $address['post_code']['long_name'];
```

Please note I have only worked on the address_components part of the JSON, the rest should be easy to work into the method though.

Comment: No worries, any time!